# Impossible to use DrawerLayout with dataBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml

I'm creating new app with MVVM architecture. So it has strong connection with dataBinding.
I want to use DrawerLayout and data Binding in MainActivity and here i have stuck, because rule for DrawerLayout root element in xml must be DrawerLayout and for success data binding, root element must be layout. Can somebody help me to combine this two root elements in correct way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actionBar_layout"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

Compiler told me that DrawerLayout can't be placed inside layout tag. If i put layout inside DrawerLayout then data binding is not working anymore

Comment: can you add error log?

Answer (score 1):

you should put the drawer layout in the layout tag, it works fine. your problem is that you are getting the drawer layout from  `android.support` but your constraint layout is from `androidx` my suggestion is to migrate to `androidx`